# How to fix: Dragged element not shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to Jquery and I am having some problem with my code. My program has a container and a small menu below. I have some img elements class piece that I can drag to my container and move around. I want to drop some other img element class cap inside my dragged piece items but when I drop the cap over the piece it didn't show up. When I see the console log I can see that the element has a child element but I cannot see it. What do you think is my problem?

```
var x = null;
$( function () {
    $(".piece").draggable({
        cancel: "a.ui-icon", 
        revert: "invalid", 
        helper: 'clone',
        containment: '#container',
    });
    $(".piece").droppable({
       accept: ".cap",
       drop: function( event, ui ) {
         x= ui.helper.clone();
         x.appendTo(this);
         }
    });
    $(".cap").draggable({
        cancel: "a.ui-icon",
        helper: 'clone',
        containment: '#container',   
    });
    $("#container").droppable(
        {
       accept : ".piece",
       drop : function(event, ui)
        {
        x = ui.helper.clone();
        x.css("width", 200);
        x.css("height", 200);                
        x.draggable({
            containment: '#container',
            cursor: 'move',
        });
        x.appendTo(this);
        x.droppable({
            accept: ".cap",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                x= ui.helper.clone();
                x.css("width", 200);
                x.css("height", 200);
                alert(' was dropped onto me!' ); 
                x.appendTo(this);
                console.log("this");
                console.log(this);
            }
        });
        ui.helper.remove();      
        }  
    });

});
```

I expect the output to be the cap over the piece but the cap didn't show over the piece. You can see the fiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/littletrives/6ktub3a9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is placing the `cap` inside the `piece` correctly, as you have noticed.

The problem is that `<img>` elements can not contain elements (source: [img specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element), [content model nothing specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#concept-content-nothing)). Because your `cap` `<img>` is inside of the `piece` `<img>`, it is not displayed.

A solution could be to add a `<div>` with the `src` of the `piece` as a `background-image` instead of adding it as an `<img>` tag. That way, you could add the `cap <img>` inside of it.

I made a fork of your jsfiddle with a small example: https://jsfiddle.net/tp7e2no1/1/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Now I have to make the cap rotate 90º with a click while conserving the ability to drag the piece around the container, should I make the background piece a handler?

Comment: @littletrives You're welcome! Making what is the `y` variable in my example a draggable object constrained to it's parent should work. You can also add a regular `.on('click', function () { ...` handler to it for the rotation, as that will only fire if you don't move your cursor between mousedown and mouseup.

Comment: In my project I have several pieces with different behaviours, should I change the menu to be divs instead of img?

Comment: You mean the part on the bottom where you drag the elements from originally? That's really up to you, I can't really think of a strong argument why either option would be better without knowing all the context.

Comment: No need to make the y variable a draggable object to work properly, only making the .on('click', .... works. You can see it on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/littletrives/6p8grnsk/29/

Comment: I mean the lower part where you drag the elements from, as I have different pieces in the class piece and the way you make it I will have to do different piece-div's to make the different backgrounds so I think I will have to make the lower menu with divs instead of img's. Is it correct? If I want to put another different cap in front of the last one, should I make the first cap background?

Comment: Glad the on click works. Again, divs or imgs for the lower menu is really up to you, I don't know if one is better than the other